# Javascript: return the first value from arrays within an object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I am working on a javascript homework problem and am a bit stuck:

Create a function called getFirstAnimals that returns an array of all the first animals in the object. 
Example: [‘bears’,’penguins’,panther’,’flea’]

I scripted the following function:

```
var animals = { 
mammals:['bears','lions','whales','otters'], 
birds:['penguins','ducks','swans','chickens'], 
cats:['panther','mountain lion','leopard','snow tiger'], 
insects: ['flea','mosquito','beetle','fly','grasshopper']
}

function getFirstAnimals(array) {
    var firstAnimals = [];
    for (key in array) {
        firstAnimals.push(array[key].slice(0,1))
    }
    return firstAnimals;
}

console.log(getFirstAnimals(animals));
```

my problem is that the output I am generating is an array of arrays made up of the first animals, [Array[1], Array[1], Array[1], Array[1]], and not the strings, [‘bears’,’penguins’,panther’,’flea’]. Any suggestions on how to get the desired output is much appreciated.

Comment: In addition to the answers, you probably want to do a few sanity checks:  1. Check that array.hasOwnProperty(key) so you don't iterate over elements that exist in a prototype, and 2. check that array[key].length > 0 so you know there isn't an empty array.

Comment: @PMV makes good comments. Also you have named the parameter to your getFirstAnimals function "array" but what you're passing in is actually an object.

Comment: the parameter you pass to `getFirstAnimals` is not an array, it's an *object*, and if you have a global (`window.`)`key` variable, congrats you just overwrote it.

Comment: great stuff! Thank you so much. I am only 3 weeks into a beginning javascript class so all this feedback is super valuable to me.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of pushing `array[key].slice(0,1)` you need to push `array[key][0]`, where `[0]` is getting you the first item in the array.

Comment: Thank you alexoakley1. I am such a noob.

Comment: Is there a way to adjust the function so that it returns the last item in the arrays?

Comment: @aguadamuz - you can use `[array[key].length-1]` instead of `[0]` to get the last item. BTW if I answered your question you should consider [accepting](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) my answer :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
firstAnimals.push(array[key][0])
```

for that. It gets the first element from the array

Answer (score 0):

Yet another approach

```js
var animals = { 
mammals:['bears','lions','whales','otters'], 
birds:['penguins','ducks','swans','chickens'], 
cats:['panther','mountain lion','leopard','snow tiger'], 
insects: ['flea','mosquito','beetle','fly','grasshopper']
}

function getFirstAnimals(array) {
  return Object.keys(array).map(v => array[v][0]);
}

console.log(getFirstAnimals(animals));
```

Answer (score 0):

A oneliner: `console.log(animals[Object.keys(animals)[0]]);`